# CollectionView Cells not sizing properly

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a collection view with cells that are just meant to display an image and a title underneath. Everything appears right in the interface builder and with the constraints. When the view actually loads the whole image does not load and is cut off as you can see in the images below. What I would like is for the cells to size to an xth of the screen (let's say third of the screen width for simplicity) ?

NewsController

```
class NewsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    private static let headlineArticleReuseIdentifier = "HeadlineArticleCell"
    private static let categoryCellReuseIdentifier = "NewsCategoryCell"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var categoriesList: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoriesFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
    @IBOutlet weak var headlineArticlesPreviewList: UITableView!
    private var bindings = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var viewModel: NewsViewModel = NewsViewModel()
    private var headlineArticles: [Article] = []
    private var categories: [Category] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var headlineTitle: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.isSkeletonable = true
        view.showGradientSkeleton()
        headlineArticlesPreviewList.delegate = self
        headlineArticlesPreviewList.dataSource = self
        categoriesList.dataSource = self
        categoriesList.delegate = self
        
        let cancellable = viewModel.$viewState.sink(receiveValue: { state in
            switch state {
            case let .data(data):
                self.setData(data: data)
                print()
            case let .error(error):
                print(error)
            case .loading:
                self.headlineTitle.showGradientSkeleton()
                self.headlineArticlesPreviewList.showGradientSkeleton()
                print()
            }
        })
        bindings.insert(cancellable)
    }
    
    private func setData(data: NewsViewModel.ViewState.Data) {
        self.view.hideSkeleton()
        self.headlineArticles = data.headlineArticles
        self.headlineTitle.text = data.headlineCategory.displayName
        self.headlineArticlesPreviewList.reloadData()
        self.categories = data.categories
        self.categoriesList.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (tableView == headlineArticlesPreviewList) {
            return headlineArticles.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = headlineArticlesPreviewList.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: NewsViewController.headlineArticleReuseIdentifier,
            for: indexPath)
            as? HeadlineArticleTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("could not cast to headline article")
        }
        let headlineArticle = headlineArticles[indexPath.item]
        cell.setArticle(article: headlineArticle)
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.categories.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = categoriesList.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NewsViewController.categoryCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? NewsCategoryCollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError("could not cast to news category")
        }
        let newsCategory = categories[indexPath.item]
        cell.setCategory(category: newsCategory)
        cell.isInteractable = true
        cell.cornerRadius = 8
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let noOfCellsInRow = 3

        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
            + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
            + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))

        let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))

        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    }

}
```

Constraints

[image: Constraints]
Cell Image

[image: Cell Image]

Cell Size

[image]

What happens
[image: What happens]

Comment: Have you implement delegate method collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize or have you set itemSize property in collectionViewLayout? Can you provide your code snippet?

Comment: I dont see that method provided. I updated my question to show my size constraints @zhoujialei

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview check the link and the answer below. Hope you'll find your way out

Answer (score 1):

Please add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your code.

Swift

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.4,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.4)
    }
```

objective c

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    return  CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * 0.4, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did nothing.

Comment: did you check if that delegate called or not?

Comment: It is never called. I think my problem is I dont know what UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout so I am not using that. Where do I use this view? Does it replace my UICollectionViewDelegate? Am I supposed to use a different view other than UICollectionView?a

Comment: nvm I just had to create the outlet and add the flowlayout delgegate

Comment: Please right click on your collection view in storyboard and add a screenshot. And please show how did you add the delegate

Answer (score 0):

Is your collection view set to be self sizing? It looks like its using the default item sizes for the collection view. You can read more about how to implement a self sizing collectionView [here](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/collection-view-cells-self-sizing/)

Another suggestion, if you are using fix aspect ratio: 1:1 and the imageView's width is 144, just set the height constraint as 144 also and remove the aspect ratio.

Third suggestion, look at the console, are there any LayoutConstraint errors? If so, it is likely that it cannot create the 1:1 aspect ratio and breaks a constraint. You can try lowering the aspect ratio's priority to 750, it usually helps in these situation, if not, look at the first two suggestions.

Also, I see that your label is also at a fixed height, 25, so technically, your cell is 144*(144+25) so you can set your itemSize to these values and don't use self sizing altogether.

Comment: My cell is already set to a specific height and width. I updated the question to reflect that

Comment: Setting that in the cell in storyboard is not enough, see my first link "implement self sizing", in that you can see, that collectionView has delegates from which it requires the sizes for cells. Replace the self sizing parts with fixed numbers and that tutorial is good for you.

Comment: I don't know which constraints you are speaking of specifically. I have added code to my question